# Cannot pull .vim/ directory

Tags: linux, bash, vim, sh

I am using Ubuntu and MacOS, so I wanted to use same `.vimrc`, `.bashrc`, and `.vim/`.
Before this, I made dotfiles repository and pulled and moved to home directory. 
Referring this site, (https://qiita.com/okamos/items/7f5461814e8ed8916870)
 I made the sh file and pulled from my GitHub, but i t didnot work. my dotfiles will not pulled. 
my dotfiles here(https://github.com/kaede0902/dotfiles)

```sh
kaede@kaede-ThinkPad-T450:~/dotfiles$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/kaede0902/dotfiles
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

```sh
kaede@kaede-ThinkPad-T450:~/dotfiles$ ls -a
.  ..  dotfilesLink.sh  .git  README.md  .vimrc
```

```sh
kaede@kaede-ThinkPad-T450:~/dotfiles$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    .bash_profile
    deleted:    .bashrc
    deleted:    .vim/.netrwhist
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang/css.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang/haml.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang/html.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang/jade.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang/less.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang/sass.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang/scss.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lang/slim.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lorem/en.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/lorem/ja.vim
    deleted:    .vim/autoload/emmet/util.vim
    deleted:    .vim/doc/emmet.txt
    deleted:    .vim/emmet-vim.zip
    deleted:    .vim/plugin/emmet.vim
    new file:   dotfilesLink.sh
```

Comment: It looks like your dotfiles were pulled successfully , but you instantly deleted them (hence the uncommited changes). Can you share your final script that you run?

Comment: I moved the .vimrc and .vim to the ~ dir from dotfiles, but `git pull` should take the all files from my Github repository, which contain .vim and .vimrc shouldn't it? My final script was `pull`, `ls`, `status`.

Comment: In this case your pull did nothing because there are no changes on the remote that you don't have locally already.  What has happened here is that you've cloned the repo, moved the files out of the working copy (essentially deleting them from git's standpoint), then asked git to bring down any newer changes from the remote.  Since there are no new changes, nothing happens.  If you're looking to have those files in your working copy still then you shouldn't move them, you should copy them or create symlinks from your home directory into your working copy.

Comment: I understood why nothing happened. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git clone solved this. I should not use pull for this.

Comment: You can accept your answer, and if the comments weren't helpful explain a little more what you tried doing

Comment: Sorry, I just stopped pulling and just decided to use `git clone url` for the repository.